# Setting up PHP mail in Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, php, ssmtp

So I am trying to setup PHP Mail in Debian Lenny.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.thewireframecommunity.com/node/39 and I've installed ssmtp with `aptitude install ssmtp`.

My email provider is godaddy so my MX records are: [image]

And this is my ssmtp.conf file:

```
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=contact@example.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smpt.europe.secureserver.net

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=example.com

# The full hostname
hostname=smtp.europe.secureserver.net

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=NO


AuthUser=contact@example.com
AuthPass=PASSWORD
UseSTARTTLS=yes
UseTLS=yes
```

where example.com is my domain name.
I get this error:

`# ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.europe.secureserver.net:25`

When using an email client I always use smtpout.europe.secureserver.net instead of smtp... but I still get the same error when I try to change the config file.

**What I'm I doing wrong?**

Comment: I don't know GoDaddy specifically, but if your SMTP server works with SSL/TLS (not for authentication but for actual mail), then you should define that in your PHP somehow. Right now you're using the non-SSL port 25 for SMTP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. GoDaddy does not require SSL Auth for outgoing, only incoming.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you just mistyped it into this forum, but your mailhub should be smtp.europe.secureserver.net, not smpt.europe.secureserver.net.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your ISP is blocking outbound connections to port 25. Usually port 587 is an alternate.